# Not able to access values from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so..

```
{
    "Due_Date" = "2020-06-09T15:00:13";
    departmentID = 180075;
    keyPointID = "";
    id = 4;
    jobID = 180093;
    jobName = myLab;
    plantID = 1232;
    shiftID = 2;
    "smat_Leader1ID" = 43232;
    workshopID = 423423;
    workstationID = 1892074;
}
```

I'm not able to get any values except those values whose key and value is string (Like Due_Date). I have fetched it like so...

```
var Due_Date =  self.dictionary["Due_Date"]! as? String //This gives an answer
```

Similarely, if I try to fetch these values, I don't get the values

```
var Department_ID = self.dictionary["departmentID"]! as? Int ?? 0   //This gives 0
var smatLeader1ID = self.dictionary["smat_Leader1ID"]! as? Int ?? 0 //This gives 0
```

(I don't get the other values also. Just that I mentioned just 2 above)

Comment: What do you get when you put `debugPrint(self.dictionary["departmentID"]!, self.dictionary["smat_Leader1ID"]!)` ?

Comment: How do you declare your dictionary?

Comment: This is how  I declared my dictionary @pawello2222 `var dictionary : NSMutableDictionary = [:]`

Comment: It does give the value @OOPer, if I print what you suggested. But if I mention that in code, the compiler prompts to make this correction..`Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'Int?'   Insert ' as! Int'     `

Comment: I wanted to know the exact output. Was that `"180075" "43232"` or `180075 43232` ?

Comment: It would be great if you could mention which programming language you are using. It is not clear to me and your language may seem like `Python` but from other answers, it seems like you are using `Swift` or other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're force casting and not getting a crash you seem to be getting the value but you're trying to cast the value as `Int` which is failing here. Seems the value is not an `Int` type could be `String` try out this to fix it.

Replace this:

```
var Department_ID = self.dictionary["departmentID"]! as? Int ?? 0
```

With this:

```
var Department_ID = Int(self.dictionary["departmentID"] as? String ?? "0")
```